# fuzzy search for mongodb Documents

Tags: mongodb, list, pymongo, fuzzy-search

some mongo document is like that:

```
{
    "_id" : "class1",
    "member" : [
            [
                    "Tom",
                    "1057004"
            ],
            [
                    "Dean",
                    "1274858"
            ],
            [
                    "Bob",
                    "1276155"
            ],
            [
                    "Alice",
                    "1046496"
            ],
            [
                    "Max",
                    "1276063"
            ]
    ],
    "teacher" : "Jack",
    "year" : "2014"
}
```

I want a Fuzzy Search for member's name, for example only search "al" result is this document.
I can use regex for normal search,how to use it in multiple List ?

thanks

Comment: Do you want return those documents which start with `a` or you need to only matched array object. Can you post your sample output ?

Comment: @Yogesh thank u for your reply,I want match  array object use fuzzy key.

Comment: so in above case your expected output like this `{ "_id" : "class1", "member" : [ [ "Alice", "1046496" ] ] }` ? did you tried `$elemMatch` ? In `elemMatch`  only return first matched array object, if your array contains multiple matched object then `elemMatch` return only one which matched first. Or either way you should try with `aggregation`

Comment: @Yogesh I'm apologies for I didn't say it clearly. I means if I want search 'alice' ,return all  documents  include this key . so I can find how many class have this name ,how to do that?  maybe return multiple result. every class members not fixed. this is one document from data,maybe have class2 class3...